# Adjust Istio metrics -limit dimensions

Tags: istio, istio-operator

#### Problem

I am trying to modify metrics so that some of them have less dimensions than the default ones. I follow examples from [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/metrics/customize-metrics/).
My code looks like:

```yaml
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  name: my-istio-operator
  namespace: default
spec:
  values:
    telemetry:
      v2:
        prometheus:
          configOverride:
            inboundSidecar:
              stat_prefix: istio
              metrics:
                - name: requests_total
                  tags_to_remove: ["destination_canonical_revision"]
            outboundSidecar:
              stat_prefix: istio
              metrics:
                - name: requests_total
                  tags_to_remove: ["destination_canonical_revision"]
```

How I understand the code, now the `istio_request_total` should not have `destination_canonical_revision` dimensions, however it does have. Please let me know if I am doing something incorrectly or this is a bug.

#### Versions

Kubernetes: Azure Kubernetes Services (1.20.9)
Istio 1.11.4 installed with command `istioctl install --set profile=demo -y`

#### Solution

It did not work because I was using kubectl to add IstioOperator. **After I switched to istioctl, everything works as expected.**

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud providor? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I've updated the description

Comment: What exactly did you do on the prometheus site? Your yaml looks fine. How exactly did you test your situation?

Comment: I followed the example from here (https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/metrics/customize-metrics/) and after I've added IstioOperator, I check the metrics by logging into a istio-proxy of one of the podes and querying localhost:15000/stats/prometheus

Comment: and what exactly did you see when you add `localhost:15000/stats/prometheus`?

Comment: I see metrics with dimensions (including those which I'd like to remove)

Comment: How exactly did you set up your prometheus?

Comment: I followed quickstart from here (https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/integrations/prometheus/)

Comment: ok, found the issue - I was adding the IstioOperator using kubectl instead of istioctl. After I've switched to istioctl, it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Community wiki answer to summarise the problem.

OP has resolved the issue and posted the comment:

> It did not work because I was using kubectl to add IstioOperator. **After I switched to istioctl, everything works as expected.**